# Python: int() returning unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, series

I have a scenario where I cannot use Python's inbuilt rounding functions so I have written a custom rounding function but it's not giving the expected result for a particular usecase. This is what I have tried (I have kept the output as the comments):

```
import pandas as pd

def custom_rounder(value, scale):
  multiplier = 10 ** scale
  if isinstance(value, pd.Series):
      print("number: ", value)
      # number: 
      # 0    583.065
      # 1     74.040
      # Name: ItemCost, dtype: float64

      print("multiplier: ", multiplier)
      # multiplier:  100

      print("number * multiplier: ", value.apply(lambda number: number * multiplier))
      # number * multiplier:
      # 0    58306.5
      # 1     7404.0
      # Name: ItemCost, dtype: float64

      print("number * multiplier + 0.5 :", value.apply(lambda number: number * multiplier + 0.5))
      # number * multiplier + 0.5 :
      # 0    58307.0
      # 1     7404.5
      # Name: ItemCost, dtype: float64


      print("int(number * multiplier + 0.5) :", value.apply(lambda number: int(number * multiplier + 0.5)))
      # int(number * multiplier + 0.5) :
      # 0    58306
      # 1     7404
      # Name: ItemCost, dtype: int64
      
      return value.apply(lambda number: int(number * multiplier + 0.5) / float(multiplier))

  elif isinstance(value, pd.DataFrame):
      return value.apply(lambda number: number.apply(lambda x: (x * multiplier + 0.5) / float(multiplier)))
  else:
      rounded_value = int(value * multiplier + 0.5) / float(multiplier)
      return rounded_value


data = {'ItemID': [1, 2],
        'ItemDescription': ['ItemA', 'ItemB'],
        'ItemCost': [945.0, 120.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# ItemID ItemDescription  ItemCost
# 1      ItemA            945.0
# 2      ItemB            120.0

print(custom_rounder(df['ItemCost'] * 0.617, 2))
# 0    583.06
# 1     74.04
# Name: ItemCost, dtype: float64
```

When I perform:

1. `int(583.065 * 100 + 0.5)` - I get the expected output as `58307`
2. `value.apply(lambda number: int(number * multiplier + 0.5))` - I get unexpected output as `58306` instead of `58307`. In this case, `int(number * multiplier + 0.5)` is behaving strangely.

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past few days but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution. What could be the reason behind this strange behavior?

Comment: From a first look, could it be because of floating point errors? I don't know what operations and roundings and decimal places you're using/doing to get to the final stage. For example, `int(0.999999999999999)` is `0`, but becomes `1` after a couple of places. From keywords in your code, I'd assume you're working with prices? I'd suggest always working with cents from the beginning, instead of dollars and cents as decimals. Only at the end, divide by `100` to get the dollar value

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I am doing what you mentioned but the problem is that int() is not performing as expected though.

Comment: Try `print(f'{number * 100 + 0.5:0.60}'` which will print many digits to give you the true number.  You might be surprised.  Don't *ever* expect `+ 0.5` to always round properly.

Comment: @MarkRansom  Hi, thank you for responding! Can you please explain what this particular line does? What can I do to fix the function `custom_rounder`?

Comment: Pandas has a [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), if you can use it: value.apply(lambda number: number * multiplier + 0.5).round()

Comment: It prints the number with enough digits to see the true value, without the rounding that Python ordinarily applies when it prints a float.